# ZKP but the verifier knows all possible secrets

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Is there a (preferably simple) implementation of ZKP where the verifier already knows the set of possible secrets? Especially if the set is very small (even as few as 2 or 3 options). The prover must convince the verifier that she possesses one of the secrets, but not which one.

Comment: What is exactly the statement you want to prove in zero-knowledge?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing to me. Usually with ZKPs you prove that you know some $w$ for some public $x$ such that some function $F(x,w)$ returns true. How many such valid $w$ there are for each $x$ is up to $F$ and it can be as low as $1$. There are also more composite variants which may be what you want where you prove that you know _one_ $w$ for a list of $x_i$ such that $\exists i: F(x_i,w)=1$.

Comment: Simply put, the verifier knows a secret set, let's say $\{ 123, 456 \}$. The prover wants to prove that she is aware of (at least) one element from that set, without disclosing which one. How can I improve the question?

Answer (score 1):

The statement to prove could be like, the secret committed is one from a set of secrets committed earlier. Probably ["OR protocol"](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eberry/papers/crypto94.pdf) would fit such a scenario.

Comment: unless I misunderstood the question, the "secret" here also includes the randomness of the commitment. By my understanding, what the OP asks about is for proofs with a small number of possible witnesses - which are always trivial

Comment: This is my understanding too: a small set of secrets and sigma protocols instantiated for each such secret/witness, OR-connected according to Cramer-Damgard-Schoenmakers paper.

Comment: ha, my comment is not correct then, I now understand OP's question with the clarification in their comment, and I think your answer is correct